# How to dispose of StreamBuilder value on sign out?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to retrieve user profiles to each user's account on sign in. Each user's information is stored in a doc with their respective uid's.

When a user registers and logs in, the data associated with the user displays correctly. However, when I create a second account and log in, the data associated with the second user displays for user 2 and user 1.

How do I dispose of the values in Streambuilder so each signed in user can see their profiles uniquely?

My code is below with a screenshot of my database

[image: firestore db]

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
  final Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> db = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('Profile')
      .doc('Personal details')
      .snapshots();



                     Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text('First name'),
                        SizedBox(width: 40),
                        StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          stream: db,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError)
                              return Text('Something went wrong');
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting)
                              return CircularProgressIndicator();

                            dynamic data = snapshot.data!.data();
                            return Text(data['First name']);
                            // return Text('First name', style: boldFont);
                          },
                        ),
                      ]),
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Last name'),
                      SizedBox(width: 40),
                      StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                        stream: db,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError)
                            return Text('Something went wrong');
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting)
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();

                          dynamic data = snapshot.data!.data();
                          return Text(data['Last name'], style: boldFont);
                          // return Text('Last name', style: boldFont);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

My sign out code

```
onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                          errorMessage = '';
                        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                          errorMessage = error.message!;
                        }
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/signIn');
                        setState(() {});
                      }
```

Comment: Can you include your current sign out code?

Comment: Hi Victor, I have added my sign out code

Answer (score 0):

I think will need `StreamSubscription` to subscription event from `Stream`.
When user signin success you will listent data on this `subscription`. When user sign out, you will `cancel` current `subscription`.
Example:

```
_streamSubscriptionMessage = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('users')
        .child(sl.get<AuthCubit>().getUid().toString())
        .child('badgeMessage')
        .onValue
        .map<int>((event) {
      try {
        return event.snapshot.value as int;
      } catch (error) {
        return 0;
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StatefulWidget`, add a state variable to store current user, build using this, and apply `setState` whenever Firebase Authentication state changes:

```
User? _currentUser; // define in the widget's state class.

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (_currentUser == null) {
    // you can add something here
    return;
  }
  final Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> db = 
  FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(_currentUser.uid),
      .collection('Profile')
      .doc('Personal details')
      .snapshots();
  // rest of your build
}
```

And add this to you Firebase Authentication listener or create if you don't have yet:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? firebaseUser) {
  setState(() {
    _currentUser = firebaseUser;
  });
});
```

(It is a good idea to define this `_currentUser` at the main application level, and use `ChangeNotifierProvider` / `Consumer` / `context.read` etc.)

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm still a beginner, much of what you have prescribed I am not able to implement successfully as I don't understand how it pieces together when you say ''add state variable to store current user, build using this, and apply setState whenever Firebase Authentication state changes'' and I do not have a Firebase Auth listener

Answer (score 0):

In case the other solutions posted were not successful, you can attempt to follow [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57143742/16929894) that involves a related problem with StreamBuilder, and use a [ListView builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) with an [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) according to the accepted answer. In this case, the [setState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) method will completely rebuild the ListView each time there is a change in the data.

Please note that these documents are external documentation and not GCP official, so I cannot vouch for their accuracy.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: I read your other comment in this thread and I would recommend reviewing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxu4bMpPvCQ) about implementing Firebase Authentication for user sign-ins. It specifically uses Streambuilder to achieve the functionality. Additionally [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state) is the documentation about integrating Firebase authentication with Flutter. I cannot vouch for the accuracy of any external GCP documentation.